# find an id in embedded document node mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a model of courses with the following structure:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const user_shortid = require('shortid');

// Create Course schema

const CourseSchema = new Schema({

    courseDetail: {
        type: String
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    enrolledUsers: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    }],
    currentStatus: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Planned'
    }

});

mongoose.model('courses', CourseSchema);
```

I have created a post request for adding a signed in user to the array of enrolledUsers, the problem is, I want to check first if the req.user.id exists in the enrolledUsers array. Following is my post request:

```
router.post('/joincourse', [ensureAuthenticated], (req, res) => {

    Course.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.coursecode },
        { $push: { enrolledUsers: req.user.id } },
        { safe: true, upsert: true },
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'Could not enroll in the course');
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            } else {
                req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now enrolled in the course');
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Right now the behavior is that a user can enroll again and again in the same course.

Is there some way I can check for the req.user.id in the enrolledUsers array before it is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do find the user first by using find() and then if a user exists, update it , else 
give an error like this

```
    router.post('/joincourse', [ensureAuthenticated], (req, res) => {

        Course.findById({ _id: req.body.coursecode },
            function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    req.flash('error_msg', 'Could not enroll in the course');
                    res.redirect('/dashboard');
                } else {
                 if(doc){
                     if(!doc.enrolledUsers.includes(req.user.id)){ // here is the checking 

                         doc.enrolledUsers.push(req.user.id);
                         doc.save();
                         req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now enrolled in the course');
                         res.redirect('/dashboard');
                     }
                }else{ 
                    // show error msg
                }

                }
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but I am confused, where are we checking if the user has already enrolled in the course and exists in the enrolledUsers array?

Comment: sorry i missed It here now it should be fine

Comment: Sorry...doesn't work. gives me the error:

MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll

Nothing gets saved in the DB but I get the success message.

Comment: try console logging doc.enrolledUsers array to see whether it pushes data in to the array

Comment: It seems like the support for pushAll was depracated. I have turned it on using mongoose.plugin(schema => { schema.options.usePushEach = true }); in my schema. Now it save the document. But the check is not working. I just saved the same user who was already registered.. So it seems like the check part of enrolledUsers is not working.

Comment: I think the problem is you mongo version is it 3.5 ? if so that's the case because mongodb 3.5 is an unstable dev release and should not be used. $pushAll has been deprecated for a long time.. if not try adding { enrolledUsers: [Schema.Types.ObjectId] }, { usePushEach: true }

Comment: Did that and the data is being saved now. But the check is not working.

Comment: it because the Array type is Object type and the comparison is done using string try converting object id to string

Comment: In your Schema change this enrolledUsers: [{
        type:String,
        ref: 'users'
    }]

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
(node:8144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: courses validation failed: enrolledUsers: Cast
to [undefined] failed for value "["5c1def67d74413392c86aa14","5c1def67d74413392c86aa14","5c1def67d74413392c86aa14"]" at path "enrolledUsers"


Also...isn't there a way to compare the ids without changing to String???

Comment: you can use ref even the ref type is String if that's what you are worried about...

Comment: if changing the Schema type gave you this error then you will have to cast them to string by iteration using a loop

Comment: how did u change the Schema ?

Comment: Can you elaborate by example please

Comment: I just changed it in the model file. Do I need to recreate the course in order for this to take effect?

Comment: yeah I guess.. try doing it because now you have the data as ObjectIds in your database. so that's why its throwing the error

Comment: Ok...did that and now the error is gone. Also enrolled the same user twice but only one entry was made. Although I am still getting the you are now enrolled success message. I guess the if statements flow needs to be adjusted.

Comment: yeah just that just change the flow that's it. If you find this was helpful mark the answer as correct

Comment: Thanks man...much appreciate it and will mark it as helpful. Cheers!

Comment: take a look at the code again I have posted i have adjusted it so the flow will be ok

Comment: Really appreciate it :-)